# Boostrap Form wont submit data to database

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap form within a modal but i cant get the data to submit to my database

my modal form (html)

```
<div class="modal-body">

      <form method="post"  action="insertRecord.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"  class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtLastName" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="emailAddress">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="txtPassword" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Dob">Date of birth:</label>
          <input type="date" name="DoB" class="form-control" id="inputDOB" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Address1">Address1</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtAddress1" class="form-control" id="inputAddress1" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Address2">Address2</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtAddress2" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtPostcode" class="form-control" id="inputPostcode" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="taxSubmit"  />
      </form>

    </div>
```

my code to insert the form info (php)

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$firstName=$_POST['txtFirstName'];
$lastName=$_POST['txtLastName'];
$email=$_POST['txtEmail'];
$password=$_POST['txtPassword'];
$dob=$_POST['DoB'];
$address1=$_POST['txtAddress1'];
$address2=$_POST['txtAddress2'];
$postcode=$_POST['txtPostcode'];


$query="INSERT INTO Userinfo (FirstName, LastName, 
Email,Password,Dob,Address1,Address2,Postcode) VALUES ('$firstName', 
'$lastName', 
'$email','$password','$dob','$address1','$address2','$postcode')";




mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
```

I have another script that connects to the database, I would appreciate any help I can get as I have been stuck on this for many hours and cannot get my head around the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @JosanIracheta No errors, the data i type into the form just wont post into the database.

When i manually go to the insertrecord.php it does work because it inserts just blank data into the database.

Comment: You need to check for errors. You are either not connecting or your query is failing. Look into mysql_error: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: 1) make sure you get the information.  In insertRecord.php, add a print_r($_POST); and ensure you get the fields from the form.  2) Then debug the INSERT.  Again, print your query and make sure it is ok.  You can print the query and run it manually to verify.  3) Then you look at your PHP insert code.

Comment: @Nic3500 Maybe i was not very specific, the problem is that when i enter the data into the form and press the submit button, nothing actually happens, the data stays there and i error checked and it connects and everything its just when i press the submit button nothing happens.

Comment: @JosanIracheta when i included the error checking it says 0: 0: i dont know what this means sorry please could you explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example, I ran and works fine for me:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';

$firstName = $lastName = $email = $email = $password = $dob = $address1 = $address2 = $postcode = $query = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $firstName = $_POST['txtFirstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['txtLastName'];
    $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    $dob = $_POST['DoB'];
    $address1 = $_POST['txtAddress1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['txtAddress2'];
    $postcode = $_POST['txtPostcode'];


    $query = "INSERT INTO Userinfo (FirstName, LastName, 
    Email, Password, Dob, Address1, Address2, Postcode) VALUES ('$firstName', 
    '$lastName', '$email','$password','$dob','$address1','$address2','$postcode')";
}
echo $query;
if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query. "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Insert Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Modal</h2>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <form method="post"  action="">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtFirstName"  class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtLastName" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emailAddress">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="txtEmail" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="txtPassword" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Dob">Date of birth:</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="DoB" class="form-control" id="inputDOB" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Address1">Address1</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtAddress1" class="form-control" id="inputAddress1" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Address2">Address2</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtAddress2" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtPostcode" class="form-control" id="inputPostcode" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="taxSubmit"  />
                            </form>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not get any errors because the real problem is that when i press the submit button with the data in the form, nothing happens, the data doesn't get send anywhere and nothing changes, like it doesn't post to the database or something. I ran the error checks and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you do echo $query;  and be sure that script post the data? for example: the ouptut similiar to this: INSERT INTO Userinfo (FirstName, LastName, Email,Password,Dob,Address1,Address2,Postcode) VALUES ('JHON', 'DOE', 'mail@mail.com','ssss','1986-11-01','ADDR1','ADDR2','999')

Comment: did echo $query; and nothing happened, it didn't run the insertRecord.php , the data i input into the form just stays there and the submit button doesn't work.